# If $L/k$ is Galois and $k\subseteq K$ is any field extension, is $LK$ Galois over $L$

Tags: galois-theory

There is a theorem in Lang which says that if $L/k$ is Galois and $k\subseteq K$ is any field extension, if $L,K$ are subfields of a larger field, then $LK$ is Galois over $K$. I was wondering if $LK$ is also Galois over $L$?

I think this would be true if $K\subseteq L$ since then we can apply the same theorem to the extension $K\subseteq LK$ and use that $(LK)L=LK$. Is that right?

Comment: I don't understand your second question... If $K\subseteq L$, then $LK=L$ which is trivially Galois over $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: let $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, and $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

Then $LK=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is not Galois over $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, because $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $L$, $LK$ contains one of its roots, but it does not contain the complex roots of $x^3-2$.

(If $K\subseteq L$, then you aren't doing anything...)

Answer (score 3):

No, in general $LK$ is not Galois over $L$.
Indeed, take $L=k$. Then $LK=K$ and the question becomes :

$$\text {Is an arbitrary field extension } \;K/k  \; \text {Galois?} $$
Need I answer?